# JPQL JOIN between 2 tables

Tags: java, jpa, join, jpql

I'm trying to join two tables but I can't manage to find a proper JPQL query.

Here's a light version of the two tables I have, there's a FK between the two id_persona columns.

```
TABLE macchine

marca (String) -- targa (String) -- id_persona (int)

TABLE persone

nome (String) -- id_persona (int)
```

What I'd like is to achieve joining them on id_persona but there's no way I can guess the query sintax and google isn't of any help.

For example, how can I get that every "targa" linked by an "id_persona" to a given "nome"?

---

Persona

```
    @Entity
    public class Persone implements Serializable {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     @Column(name="id_persona")
     private int idPersona;

     private String cognome;

     private Timestamp data_nascita;

     private String nome;



     @OneToMany(mappedBy="persona")
     @JoinColumn(name="id_persona")
     private Set<Macchine> macchina;
    }
```

-

Macchine

```
@Entity
public class Macchine implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name="id_persona")
 private int idPersona;

 private String targa;

 private String marca;



 @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
 private Persone persona;
}
```

--

Query

```
public static List<Macchine> selectPM(){
        Query selectAll = em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM Macchine m");
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Macchine> jObj = selectAll.getResultList();
        return jObj; //Join Objective
    }
```

I edited the answer because I made some changes in the project. I have new tables which I linked.

This is the error I'm getting now:

```
Error compiling the query [SELECT m.id_persona, m.targa, m.marca FROM Macchine m], line 1, column 9: unknown state or association field [id_persona] of class [model.Macchine]
```

Comment: When asking about JPQL we don't need the tables but the _entities_. When dealing with tables you'd use plain SQL.

Comment: You're right, editing real quick

Comment: So now add a relation between the 2 classes, because you won't be joining them in JPQL without it

Comment: Why aren't the entities linked directly, e.g. why doesn't `Persone` have a reference to `Indirizzi` and vice versa? Note that (at least with Hibernate) `Indirizzi` could use it's reference to a `Persone` as its id. That way the query would be easy: `SELECT i.indirizzo FROM Indirizzi i WHERE i.persone.nome = :whatever`. Without the direct link you need a cross join: `SELECT i.indirizzo FROM Indirizzi i, Persone p WHERE p.idPersona = i.idPersona AND p.nome = :whatever`.

Comment: Entities aren't linked because I'm very new to this topic and thought I had to join them by the JPQL query..
How can I link them?

Comment: you link them by reading a JPA reference document, which explains about `@OneToOne` relations for example. Here's one http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/mapping.html#one_one_relations

Comment: Ok, I managed (?) to link the entities, now I'm getting an error on the query..